# Eclipse/EGit: How to Build a Specific Tag of Git Repo

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I want to build v 1.8.4 of the Amazon AWS SDK. When I clone the git repo I get the master branch, probably the HEAD. I do not see any place to configure the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see the tags with:

```
 git tag
```

(like the tags of [`aws/aws-sdk-java`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/tags))

You [see the tags in the repository view](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Branch_and_Tag_Support):

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/e/e1/RepoMgrBranchesAndTags.png]

---

From there, you should be able to checkout any tag you want in order for your working tree to reflect that tag:

```
git checkout 1.8.4
```

For keeping the branches as is, but accessing a particular/commit or tag, one can use the [Egit checkout](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Checkout), as suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706718/eclipse-egit-how-to-build-a-specific-tag-of-git-repo/24710126?noredirect=1#comment38341247_24710126) by [robinst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305973/robinst).

> you just wanted to change the "current branch" to the commit of the tag.
>   To check out a tag, use the context menu on the tag

---

You also can [reset to a specific tag](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Reset_to_specific_branch_or_tag):

> Select `Team -> Reset...` on a project.
>   This opens a dialog where you can select a branch or a tag.

But that would change the current branch, which might not be what you want.

Comment: how to do this in eclipse egit view?

Comment: Reset does *not* do what you want here. E.g. when you're currently on `master` and reset to a tag, that means `master` now points to the commit of the tag. Instead, you just wanted to change the "current branch" to the commit of the tag. To check out a tag, use the context menu on the tag.

Comment: @robinst but if you checkout a tag, your head will be detached, won't it? (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Checkout)

Comment: Yes, that's what you want in this case (and the thing that CLI does as well). Or maybe I didn't understand the question. But if the CLI answer is `git checkout`, then the EGit answer is not *Reset...*.

Comment: @robinst Ok, I have added that option to the answer.

Comment: Better, but it still looks like `git checkout` is the same as `EGit Reset`, which is wrong and dangerous. I would switch the order to make it clear that `EGit's Reset` does not do what `git checkout` does (it does what `git reset` does).

Comment: @robinst Ok. switched.