# How to import a git project based on a revision in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git

Is it possible to checkout code from a GIT repository based on an old revision. For example, I would like to checkout as a new application a code base I have but around the time when the code was first created (i.e revision 10 or so)

i don't seem to see this option available in eclipse.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in "[Eclipse/EGit: How to Build a Specific Tag of Git Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24710126/6309)", you could use the "[EGit Checkout](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Checkout)", but your [HEAD would be detached](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#.22Detached.22_HEAD).

It is easier to open the [History view](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#History_View), and [create a branch from the right commit](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#From_the_History_View_2).
(right click on the right commit in the "commit graph" section of that view)

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/d/df/Egit-0.9-history-view.png]